# Force py.test to use installed version of module

Tags: pytest

I have a mixed Python/C++ library with test files mixed in amongst source files in the same directories.  The layout looks like

```
/home/irving/geode
  geode
    __init__.py
    vector
      __init__.py
      test_vector.py
      ...
    ...
```

Unfortunately, the library is unusable in-place since it lacks .so extension modules.  **Question**: Can I make py.test always use an installed version, even when run from `/home/irving/geode` or a subdirectory?

The test files have `from __future__ import absolute_import`, and run fine if executed directly as scripts.  For example, if I do

```
cd geode/vector
./test_vector.py
```

which does `import geode`, it finds the installed version.  However, if I run py.test in `geode/vector`, it finds the local copy of `geode`, and then dies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have two options:

1. run `py.test --pyargs geode.vector.test_vector` to make pytest interpretet the argument as an import path, deriving the file system path from it.  This should run the test against the installed version.
2. move the tests out into a `tests` directory without an `__init__.py` file.  This way you need to `pip install -e .` to work in-place or can do `python setup.py install` and the `py.test tests` to run tests against the installed version.

Comment: Actually, without an `__init__.py`, setuptools cannot find test directory as a package, if you are using `find_packages()` in my experience. Therefore, `tests` directory will not be delivered on your `site-packages`. I choose to include a `__init__.py` and it works perfectly with `py.test --pyargs mypackage`.