# Python: run tests from wheel or sdist

Tags: python, testing, build, setuptools, python-wheel

For a package I've authored, I've done `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, which generates some package artifacts in the `dist/` directory.  Now I'd like to run the package's unit tests in those artifacts.  What's a good way to do it?

To be clear: an alternative would be to run the tests directly from the local source files, but I want to avoid that to make sure I'm testing the exact pre-built artifact users would be installing ([as suggested here](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#upload-your-distributions)).

I'm using Python 3, and I'm on a Linux or Mac OS environment.  My context is a build server that builds, tests, and then publishes artifacts (to a private PyPI-like repo) as commits are made to a Git repository.

If there's some other approach I should be using instead, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do is:

- Create a virtual environment
- Install your package
- Run the tests against your installed library using tools like pytest, you can read more about pytest good practices here: http://pytest.org/dev/goodpractises.html

As pointed in the pytest docs take a look to [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as well for your CI server: http://pytest.org/dev/goodpractises.html#use-tox-and-continuous-integration-servers

This is a related question regarding how to test using the installed package: [Force py.test to use installed version of module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530849/force-py-test-to-use-installed-version-of-module)

Comment: Cool, it looks like 'tox' will handle much of the details for me.  Thanks.