# How to prevent pytest using local module

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, pythonpath

For reference, this is the **opposite** of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253826/path-issue-with-pytest-importerror-no-module-named-yadayadayada). That question asks how to get pytest to use your local module. I want to *avoid* pytest using the local module.

I need to test my module's installation procedure. We should all be testing our modules' installation procedures. Therefore, I want my test suite to pretend like it's any other python module trying to import my module, which I have installed (whether or not it's up to date with my latest edits and/or an editable install is my business).

My project layout looks like this:

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_module.py
├── setup.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_my_package.py
```

If I

```
pip install .
cd tests
python -c "import my_package"
```

it all works. However, if I

```
pip install .
pytest
```

it does not. This is because pytest automatically adds the calling directory to the `PYTHONPATH`, making it impossible to test that `pip install` has worked. I want it to not do that.

I need to do this because I am using `setuptools-scm` (which has different behaviour in editable and non-editable installs) and `setuptools.find_packages`, which makes it easy to ignore subpackages. However, to reiterate, my issue is with pytest's discovery, not with the use of these two utilities.

Comment: What if you `cd` into `tests` before running pytest?

Comment: Same behaviour. A workaround is to add `import sys; sys.path.pop(0)` to my `conftest.py` before `import my_module`, but it's not pretty.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate but the answer is not too convincing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530849/force-py-test-to-use-installed-version-of-module

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be the same issue - didn't show up in my searches. But you're right, no satisfying answers.

Answer (score 2):

See docs for [pytest import mechanisms and `sys.path`/`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/explanation/pythonpath.html), which describe three import modes, which control this behavior. For instance, try this:

```
$ pytest --import-mode=importlib
```

which uses [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) to import test modules, rather than manipulating `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to manually edit the PYTHONPATH by changing `tests/conftest.py` to include

```py
import sys
sys.path.pop(0)
```

before the first time `my_module` is imported, but it's not pretty and makes the assumption about where in the PYTHONPATH that item is going to show up. Of course, more code could be added to check explicitly, but that's really ugly:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
project_dir = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent)
sys.path = [p for p in sys.path if not p.startswith(project_dir)]
```